# No Vertical Gridlines?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a small problem with Core-Plot library (1.5.1 version). I'm creating application for iOS that plots some data collected from the Internet. I want to display vertical grid lines, I'm using custom labeling so I have to set `majorTickLocations` on my own. Everything works OK, but the problem is, when all data that I want to plot has a value of 0.0, the vertical grid lines do not appear.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I was my mistake. The problem occured beacuse I have some logic for rescaling plotSpace when I reload plot. So when all data has 0.0 values my logic set plotSpace range as [0, 0] (range starts from 0 and has 0 length). There was simply no space for gridlines.